# Python Calling a function within a class, within a function, from an imported module

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

I have this problem. I have 2 files at the moment. I am trying to print the words "Hello World Trudy". I can't get around doing it. It keeps telling me I have an attribute error. What should I do to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Trudy\Desktop\PythonLearning\test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    f.sayHello()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'C'
```

test1.py

```
def main():
    class C:
        def function6(self):
            print ("Hello")
        def function7(self):
            print ("Trudy")
    def sayHello():
        C().function6()
    def sayWorld():
        C().function7()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

test2.py

```
import test1
def function2():
    print ("World")

test1.main().C.function6()
function2()
```

Comment: What's up with that `main` function? Why does it exist? Also, you're only using one Python version. Don't tag multiple.

Comment: `main()` is a function that doesn't return anything (hence its return type is `NoneType`). You cannot access classes defined inside a function block from outside the block.

Comment: Why are you declaring a class inside of a function?  Why are you doing `C().function6()` instead of storing an instance of `C` somewhere?  What exactly are you trying to do?  What problem are you trying to solve with this code?

Comment: Some recommended reading https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html, 
And as the docs suggest, please read about scope and namespacing first.

Comment: Hey guys sorry about that. I'm really new to Python! Will be reading the docs and trying to figure out. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a main function in test1 file. Just have the Class C in there.

**test1.py**

```
class C:
    def function6(self):
        print ("Hello")
    def function7(self):
        print ("Trudy")
 def sayHello():
    C().function6()
 def sayWorld():
    C().function7()
```

**test2.py**

```
import test1
def function2():
    print ("World")

test1.C().function6()
function2()
```